# Using adb to move data to new device

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-tab, data-transfer, app-data, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy Tab S3. I used Samsung Smart Switch and I have Google set to backup my data and restore it. But on all the apps that got automatically restored there was none of my data. I was looking at ADB and saw the backup option. So I was wondering if doing `adb backup -f ./samsung.bk -obb -all -nosystem` and then restoring the backup file to my new device would work or just brick it? My current device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab S. I used `-nosystem` so it wouldn't overwrite the core system files.

Many thanks is advanced.
Geoffrey S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. At the very least it won't brick since it doesn't include system apps. You could also try adding `-shared` to your backup command.